# issue in getting mp3 files from other drive

Tags: php, file, directory, file-handling

i'm facing issue in displaying mp3 files from another drive. In console.log it displays error has `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404`

Now i have music files store in `D:\music files`
And my php file path is `C:\wamp\www\php examples\php file handling system\files.php`

Now how can i get the music files from `D:\music files` folder and display it in webpage.

Here is my php code :

```
 <?php
    $dir_path = 'D:\music files';
    $options = '';

    if(is_dir($dir_path)){
        $files = opendir($dir_path);

        if($files){
            while(( $file_name = readdir($files)) !== FALSE){
                if($file_name != '.' && $file_name != '..'){
                    $op[] = array (
                        'name'=>$file_name
                    );
                    $options =  $options.'<option>'.$file_name.'</option>';
                    //echo $file_name."<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Displaying in html table

```
 <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Music</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $k = 1;
                        foreach($op as $row){
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $k;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
                            <td><audio controls>
                              <source src="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
                            Your browser does not support the audio element.
                        </audio></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php   
                            $k++;
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: As a thought experiment also try deleting all code from that file and replacing it with an `echo "test";` to see if the server actually is running any PHP code from it

Comment: @apokryfos  its localhost  php code is running fine. i need the right url to access the mp3 file which are in `D:` drive

Comment: You need to allow apache to serve files from that folder, it won't do that by default. Simplest thing to do is create a directory junction (or symbolic link in linux) that would make the `D:\music files` directory point to a (sub)directory contained in your apache document root. If this is just for personal use then also `file://D:\music files\mysong.mp3` might also work

Comment: @apokryfos how can i let apache allow to access files from other drive

Comment: If you want to serve that directory to others and don't want to make a junction then you need to make a virtual host and set that directory as its root. That's not a simple task so I suggest you google it.

Answer (score 0):

From php documments:

```
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);
```

this list all files from path 'dir', and you can put this into foreach and list all files from music path into table, but if you want get only music files you needed use glob. [PHP DOCS::Glob function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: my files are in `D:` drive i wanted the right url to access it